# How do i animate my player using the new input system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm using Brakeys animation guide here:[Movement thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8&t=474s)
which is set in the old Input system.
Im making a mobile game, therefore using the new input system, but the line "horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;" Doesn't work

When i load into the game, i get this error message: 'Assets\PlayerMovement.cs(46,46): error CS0103: The name 'horizontalMove' does not exist in the current context' pops up.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;
    
    [Header("Movement Variables")]
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveVector;
    public float jumpDistance;
    public float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] bool isFacingRight;


    [Header("Ground Check")]
    [SerializeField] bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundSpot;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        isFacingRight = true;
    }

    public void Move(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        moveVector = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();


    }

    public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if(context.performed && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpDistance);
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        horizontalMove =  Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundSpot.position, 0.1f, groundLayer);
        CheckDirection();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveVector.x * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

    }


    void CheckDirection()
    {
        if(moveVector.x > 0 && !isFacingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if(moveVector.x < 0 && isFacingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }   

    void Flip()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 180, 0));
    }

}
```

Please help

I tried changing it to other things in the script, like rb.velovity and 'Move' but they both come up with the same problem

Comment: The variable was never declared.  Declare the variable locally or at the class level.

Comment: I'm new to this and have no idea what you mean by that. Could you please elaborate? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Like hijinxbassist said in his comment, the variable `horizontalMove` wasn't declared anywhere. I replaced it with `moveVector.x`.
I also deleted `horizontalMove =  Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;` because it was conflicting with the `Move()` thing